# Create separate instance of service for @nestjs/bull

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to make parallel queues for video processing.

However, I've faced problem in doing so. Below is the diagram of what i am trying to achieve.

[image]

**Flow is:**

1. User sends `GET` request to the `/process` endpoint (actually, GET is only for testing, it rather uses `@MessagePattern` to receive data from other service)
2. This request contains `ModelDTO` as well as `sequence` which is used for internal tracking
3. Controller imports `private readonly _queueService: QueueService` via constructor
4. It then calls `this._queueService.process({ model, sequence })`
5. `QueueService` imports `@InjectQueue('video_processor') private readonly _processorQueue: Queue` via constructor
6. `QueueService` simply calls `this._processorQueue.add('process', data);`
7. `VideoProcessor` imports `private readonly _videoService: VideoService` via constructor
8. Inside `VideoProcessor` there is a method with `@Process('process')` decorator
9. Inside this method I am awaiting for the result from the service with `await this._videoService.configure(job.data).process()`

**And here is the problem:**

1. Whenever I am trying to run 1 job at a time (sending single request and actually waiting for job to complete) everything works just fine
2. If I am queueing two jobs at the same time, for some reason, the `console.log(this._videoData.id)` inside `VideoService` will now return the ID of the second model rather than actual ID.

So far I have tried adding `scope: Scope.TRANSIENT` to almost all services with no luck. Seems like i just can't figure out where this scope should be added.

[image]

I am expecting for 10 jobs to be able to run in parallel, however, if I add more than 1 job to the queue, they start mixing in data from the other jobs.